# How to get the state of a component in another file react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but I can't quite seem to grasp how to do it.
I have a screen that is essentially a form, but all of the components live in different files (as is usual). And what I can't grasp (and I've searched online with queries like: `How to get state of custom react component from parent` and things like that, and I can't come up with anything) is how to get the state of a component where the state changing functions live in a different file. To my understanding there is no DOM manipulation in react-native, because the way I would do this on the web would be like:

```
const stateValue = document.querySelector('#thingIWantToGetTheValueOf').value;
```

But to my knowledge you can't do that in react native. Below is the code I'm working with, then I will pare it down to a question:

```
// SubmitReferralScreen.js
      <PageTemplate headerText='New Referral' needsBackButton='true' navBar='true' needsFocus='Referrals'>
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.formContainer}>
              <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <GeneralInput autoFocus='true' labelText='Referral Name' type='default' placeholder='Full Name' />
                <GeneralInput labelText='Phone Number' type='phone-pad' placeholder='(555) 123-4567' />
                <Picker selectedValue={this.state.relationship} onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({relationship: itemValue})} style={styles.picker}>
                  <Picker.Item label='Friend' value='friend' />
                  <Picker.Item label='Family Member' value='family' />
                  <Picker.Item label='Select' value='' />
                  <Picker.Item label='Co Worker' value='coworker' />
                </Picker>
                <GeneralInput labelText='Email' type='email-address' placeholder='email@shinesolar.com' />
              </View>
              <IconButton navigateTo='YayReferral' buttonText='Submit Referral' />
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </PageTemplate>
```

```
// GeneralInput.js
export class GeneralInput extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            placeholder: this.props.placeholder,
            inputValue: "",
            inputting: false,
        };
     }
    whenInputIsFocused() {
        this.setState({placeholder: ""});
    }
    whenInputIsBlurred() {
        if (this.state.inputValue === "") {
            this.setState({placeholder: this.props.placeholder});
        }
    }
  render() {
    const autoFocus = this.props.autoFocus == 'true';
    return(
        <View style={styles.outerContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.labelText}>{this.props.labelText}</Text>
            <TextInput 
                autoCapitalize='none' 
                autoFocus={autoFocus}
                onChangeText={(inputValue) => this.setState({inputValue})}
                value={this.state.inputValue} 
                secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry} 
                onBlur={this.whenInputIsBlurred.bind(this)} 
                onFocus={this.whenInputIsFocused.bind(this)} 
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent" 
                keyboardType={this.props.type} 
                returnKeyType={this.props.returnKeyType} 
                placeholder={this.state.placeholder} 
                placeholderTextColor='rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)' 
                style={styles.inputStyles} />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In the SubmitReferralScreen, when that `IconButton` is pressed, I want to collect the values of all the GeneralInputs (and the picker) and submit the form if they pass some validation. But, because the state changing functions are held in the GeneralInput.js, I don't know how to access the state of those components.
**How do you access the state of components imported from another folder?**

Comment: add redux and use that :)

Comment: @Petrogad redux is too buggy I've heard to be truly stable for React Native, and my thoughts have always been "If x library can do it, then there has to be a way I can do it too"

Comment: I'd be curious to hear about the "buggyness" of redux. I have yet to hit any bugs with redux that weren't caused by poor coding decision on my end.  Additionally, creating anonymous functions inline (per your onChangeText) causes performance bottlenecks in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, in your `<GeneralInput>` component you would need to implement a function that passes back the data and sets the stateful information in your parent.

You then get to decide where to manage the state of `GeneralInput`, where it just communicates back (on state change) the value to a parent or if the parent manages it.

Additionally, I believe you could use a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation) on the field and pass that back however that's not really how I'd recommend going about it.

In your parent controller:

```
<GeneralInput
   autoFocus='true'
   labelText='Referral Name'
   type='default'
   placeholder='Full Name'
   onChange={this.handleChange} //added line
 />

// class method outside of render
onChange = ({key, value}) => { 
    this.setState({key, value});
}
```

// GeneralInput.js

```
<TextInput 
  onChangeText={this.storeValue}
  ...
/>

//outside of render method
storeValue = (inputValue) => {
   this.setState({inputValue})
   this.props.onChange({key: 'myField', value: inputValue})
}
```

Again, I don't recommend doing it this way at all. Top down concerns mean you need to manage things up higher or use something like mobx/redux to communicate through out and not manage this. Additionally, if you're doing it this way, I'd have the source of truth be at your parent not in the children and pass the value in accordingly.

Comment: And so I guess that's my question, how do you pass that data back?